# Minimalistic example on how to use the Undo Monad Transformer

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I was searching the web on tutorials / examples on how to use the [Undo Monad Transformer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Hedi-0.1.1/docs/Undo.html) but haven't found any.

Could someone please give a minimalistic example that shows how to use it?

Or pointing out a book where it is explained would be helpful too.

I would like to use it to implement undo/redo operations in a simple editor.

Comment: [Here's](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/New_monads/MonadUndo) the original code. It's not on Hackage however :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find any tutorials either, but I think I understand this well enough to explain.

We first need to cobble together a type to represent our editors current state, for now will just do

```
 type EditorState = Int
```

Then we can give this to our `Undo` monad

```
 type Editor = Undo EditorState
```

Now we can do something like

```
 fakeUser = do
   put 1 -- Current state is 1
   put 2 -- Current state is 2, 1 is saved in undo buffer
   put 3 -- Current state is 3, 1 and 2 are saved
   undo  -- Move 3 to redo buffer, pop 2 off of undo buffer, current state is 2
   redo  -- reverse of the above, current state is 3
```

So you can think of this as a cursor in a list*, and we can move back and forth in this list where going left means we "undo" things and going right means we "redo" things. Using `put` sticks an element into the list at the current point and moves the old element to the undo buffer.

I would recommend *not* relying on the `MonadState` instance to do insertions because it hints a bit too much at the internals of `Undo` and it complicates things if we wanted to track other state through our editor.

However, this is a pretty simple piece of code that you could update to *not* use `MonadState`, get rid of the datatype contexts, remove the dependency on `-f-glasgow-extensions` which is frowned upon and then upload to hackage as a simple library if you have a bit of time.

*The name of such a structure is a "zipper"

Comment: Is it a list? What about `put 3 >> undo >> put 4`?

Comment: It's a list zipper, look at `History` in the code @J.Abrahamson.

Comment: So it is! And `put` erases the redos. That makes more sense.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson Ah yes, I missed that on read through of the code. Out of curiosity, if someone where to modernize this is there a standard list zipper that I'm just not thinking of? It seems like there should be..